# How to get list of Departments in Active directory using C#

Tags: c#, ldap

What is the easiest way to query the Active directory to get a strings list of departments names. Example: "Finance", "Marketing", "IT",etc.
My case is an active directory for an enterprise with well over 3000 users.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assuming that you just want to get a list of objects with the Department attribute returned you could use a DirectorySearcher in the System.DirectoryServices namespace.

Then your filter would be something like:

```
ds.Filter = "(objectClass=user)";
```

and you could then tell the searcher to just load the department attribute:

```
ds.PropertiesToLoad.Add("department");
```

Then enumerate throught the result set:

```
SearchResultCollection results = ds.FindAll();
```

Then add each department property to a Dictionary to get all the unique values

```
 foreach (SearchResult result in results)
 {
   string dept = String.Empty;
   DirectoryEntry de = result.GetDirectoryEntry();
   if (de.Properties.Contains("department"))
   {
     dept = de.Properties["department"][0].ToString();
     if (!dict.ContainsKey(dept))
     {
       dict.Add(result.Properties["department"][0].ToString();
     }
  }
}
```

Alternatively, there are command-line tools which will give you this information such as dsquery or adfind.

```
adfind -default -f "(objectclass=user)" department -list | sort
```

will give you a sorted list of the department attributes for all users.

Comment: adfind is part of 'Remote Server Administration Tools (RSAT) for Windows operating systems' https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2693643 . A freeware provide improved version of these tools http://www.joeware.net/freetools/